# How Can I make sure that Subs are called after my queries refresh is complete?

Tags: excel, vba, refresh

do you know how can I make sure that all subs are called only when the query refresh is complete?

This is my code:

```
Sub RefreshContactsInMaster()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - ContactDateQuery").Refresh
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - MYFollowUpQuery").Refresh
Call NumberOfContacts
Call AverageSuccessRate
Call ContactCycle
Call LastContactDate
Call MyCondFormattingContactCycle
Call MyConditionalFormattingFollowup
MsgBox "Both Follow-ups & Contact Cycle Details have been been Updated!", vbInformation
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

What happens here is that all actions are called before the query refresh is updated.

Thank you

Comment: Set `BackgroundQuery` to False before the refresh.

Comment: Hi Thanks, I added BackgroundQuery = False to my code before the Refresh but the Subs are called anyway before the refreshes finish.  Any other idea?

Comment: That was my only suggestion - you might find other hints in these related posts - https://www.google.com/search?q=vba+ensure+queries+refreshed+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: Thank you Tim, it did work as per the link you suggested